# Extract specific cell from netlist

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, verilog

For example, the netlist is:

```
INV i0 (.I(a0),
    .O(b0));

BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
```

I would like to extract BUF cell from the netlist and write to another file.
As you know that there is always newline inside a cell of a netlist, what is the regex format to locate the cells I want to extract?

I have tried `grep ^BUF.*$` but it will only return `BUF i1 (.I(a1),` since there is a newline, I failed to extract entire BUF cell.

Answer (score 1):

**grep** solution:

```
$ grep -Poz 'BUF[^;]+;' input.txt
BUF i1 (.I(a1),
.O(b1));
BUF i1 (.I(a1),
.O(b1));
```

**awk** solution:

```
$ cat vlg.awk
BEGIN { RS="" }
/BUF/
```

**input:**

```
$ cat input.txt
INV i0 (.I(a0),
.O(b0));

BUF i1 (.I(a1),
.O(b1));

INV i0 (.I(a0),
.O(b0));

BUF i1 (.I(a1),
.O(b1));
```

**output:**

```
$ awk -f vlg.awk input.txt
BUF i1 (.I(a1),
.O(b1));
BUF i1 (.I(a1),
.O(b1));
```

or just commandline: `$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=""} /BUF/' input.txt`

`Note:`
In the awk solution, the difference between `RS=""` and `RS="\n\n+"` should be noted here. The first option ignores leading newlines in the input data and - if a file ends without extra blank lines after the last record - the final newline is removed from the record. Using the second option, this special processing is not done. Read about this in [gawk docs](http://gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html). Used comments by Ed Morton.`

Comment: You should mention that the awk solutions will only work in GNU awk due to the multi-character RS. For them to work in any awk change `RS="\n\n"` to `RS=""`. Also, in awk `/BUF/ { print $0 }` is normally written as just `/BUF/` since `{print $0}` is the default action given a true condition. If you can output multiple records you should also set `ORS="\n\n"` to match the blank-line-separated format of the input.

Comment: You should mention that `RS=""` causes leading newlines in the input data file to be ignored, and if a file ends without extra blank lines after the last record, the final newline is removed from the record. Ergo: this is a +1. The explicit print should go, I agree. The `ORS="\n\n"` addition is an assumption.

Comment: If there were any completely empty lines at the start of the file then yes they'd be ignored but a) why would they be there and b) if they were then why shouldn't they be ignored and c) the behavior of paragraph mode is already well documented and consistent with the way leading blanks in records are ignored when using the default FS - neither needs to be described each time it's used. A file ending without blank lines will not cause the final newline to be removed. Yes, an assumption has to be made about whether the OP wants newlines between output records like in his input or not.

Comment: Here's the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html

Comment: Ah, I see, now I understand why you said `if a file ends without extra blank lines after the last record, the final newline is removed from the record` - that's highlighting the possibly unexpected issue with using `RS="\n\n+"`, it's not talking about use of `-v RS=""`.

Comment: What I mean by that is - `RS=""` behaves as you'd expect (and as that sentence describes) whereas `RS="\n\n+"` would (probably unexpectedly and undesirably) leave the final newline attached to the last record in a file that didn't have trailing blank lines. That's why that sentence is in the documentation - to highlight the problem with `RS="\n\n+"`s unexpected behavior not to highlight anything about the expected behavior of `RS=""`.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/^BUF/{N;p}' file
```

When `^BUF` is found, the line is merged with next line(`N`) and output(`p`).

Answer (score 0):

**grep** oneliner

```
grep "BUF " -A1 input >> output
```

For every `BUF` match, print matched line and one line after it.

Output file:

```
BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work robustly with any awk on any UNIX system:

```
awk -v RS= '$1=="BUF"' file
```

and if you can have multiple "BUF" blocks in the input then you'll probably want the same blank line in the output as you have in the input so then you'd use this:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$1=="BUF"' file
```

The main difference between the above and any other answer so far is that since it does an exact string comparison on the first non-blanks string in each record it will work regardless of white space preceding BUF on the line, will work even if similar text (e.g. BUFFER) appears on other lines, and will work even if BUF appears in the wrong location in other parts of the file (e.g. within comments?).

For example with this input file:

```
$ cat file
INV i0 (.I(a0), # not BUF here
    .O(b0));

  BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));

BUFFER i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
```

Here is how all the proposed solutions so far will behave:

```
$ awk -v RS= '$1=="BUF"' file
  BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
$

$ sed -n '/^BUF/{N;p}' file
BUFFER i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
$

$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=""} /BUF/' file
INV i0 (.I(a0), # not BUF here
    .O(b0));
  BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
BUFFER i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
$

$ grep -Poz 'BUF[^;]+;' file
BUF here
    .O(b0));BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));BUFFER i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));$
$

$ grep "BUF " -A1 file
INV i0 (.I(a0), # not BUF here
    .O(b0));
--
  BUF i1 (.I(a1),
    .O(b1));
$
```